# What is a good starting point for a study of the early Church?

Tags: church-history, early-church, church-fathers

I'm very interested in the Early Church (after Christ's Ascension) and was wondering what Orthodox writings are available? So far, I have found Eusebius, Papias, Irenaeus, James the Martyr and Philo Judaeus. Does anyone have any additional suggestions? Basically, looking into the first century AD.

Comment: I think you should limit your question somewhat as it is quite broad.

Comment: @KenGraham done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Epistle of Polycarp to the Philippians.

This and others may be found [here](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.i.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to recommend Didache (Estimated Range of Dating: 50-120 A.D.).

Information on **Didache**:

> Since it was discovered in a monastery in Constantinople and published by P. Bryennios in 1883, the Didache or Teaching of the Twelve Apostles has continued to be one of the most disputed of early Christian texts. It has been depicted by scholars as anything between the original of the Apostolic Decree (c. 50 AD) and a late archaising fiction of the early third century. It bears no date itself, nor does it make reference to any datable external event, yet the picture of the Church which it presents could only be described as primitive, reaching back to the very earliest stages of the Church's order and practice in a way which largely agrees with the picture presented by the NT, while at the same time posing questions for many traditional interpretations of this first period of the Church's life. Fragments of the Didache were found at Oxyrhyncus (P. Oxy 1782) from the fourth century and in coptic translation (P. Lond. Or. 9271) from 3/4th century. Traces of the use of this text, and the high regard it enjoyed, are widespread in the literature of the second and third centuries especially in Syria and Egypt. It was used by the compilator of the Didascalia (C 2/3rd) and the Liber Graduun (C 3/4th), as well as being absorbed in toto by the Apostolic Constitutions (C c. 3/4th, abbreviated as Ca) and partially by various Egyptian and Ethiopian Church Orders, after which it ceased to circulate independently. Athanasius describes it as 'appointed by the Fathers to be read by those who newly join us, and who wish for instruction in the word of goodness' [Festal Letter 39:7]. Hence a date for the Didache in its present form later than the second century must be considered unlikely, and a date before the end of the first century probable. - [Jonathan Draper (Gospel Perspectives, v. 5, p. 269)](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/didache.html)